# Unique string representation of Expression<Func<T, bool>> and Func<IQueryable<T>, IIncludableQueryable<T, object>>

Tags: .net, linq, hashcode

I'm having troubles implementing a cached repository:
I'd need to get a unique identifier for these 2 objects which are a *Expression<Func<T, bool>> and Func<IQueryable*, *IIncludableQueryable<T, object>>* (T are entity objects).

The first one represent a filter to be applied to the underlying data set while the second are the needed includes.
I've tried using GetHashCode() but they'll return always the same values and I cannot get a unique value that represent them because they are dynamically built outside of the repository.

Is there any advice I could use?

This is a piece of the code that I use:

```
    public async Task<Session> GetByIdAsync(string id, bool trackChanges = true, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default,
    Func<IQueryable<Session>, IIncludableQueryable<Session, object>> includes = null, Expression<Func<Session, bool>> search = null)
{
    var cacheKey = GetKey(id, includes);
    _cache.TryGetValue<Session>(cacheKey, out var session);
    if (session == null)
    {
        session = await _dataProvider.GetByIdAsync(id, trackChanges, cancellationToken, includes, search);
        await _cache.SetAsync(cacheKey, session, _distributedCacheEntryOptions);
    }


    //session.LastChangeTime = DateTimeOffset.Now;
    return session;
}
```

This is the last version of the function I'm using to create the Cache Key:

```
    private string GetKey(string id, Func<IQueryable<Session>, IIncludableQueryable<Session, object>> includes = null,
    Expression<Func<Session, bool>> filter = null, bool trackChanges = true)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("Session:");
    sb.Append(trackChanges ? 1 : 0);
    sb.Append(":");
    sb.Append(id);
    if (includes != null)
    {
        sb.Append(includes.GetHashCode().ToString().Replace("-", ""));
    }
    if (filter != null)
    {
        sb.Append(filter.Body.ToString());
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: It is already part of the cache key if you mean the class name. Adding now to the question how the key is constructed

Comment: Do you need a unique identifier for each unique object, or are you trying to determine if two different objects represent the same `Expression` tree or `Func` delegate?